# Coq - proving something which has already been defined?

Tags: coq, proof

Taking the very straightforward proof of "the sum of two naturals is odd if one of them is even and the other odd":

```
Require Import Arith.
Require Import Coq.omega.Omega.

Definition even (n: nat) := exists k, n = 2 * k.
Definition odd  (n: nat) := exists k, n = 2 * k + 1.

Lemma sum_odd_even : forall n m, odd (n + m) -> odd n /\ even m \/ even n /\ odd m.
Proof.
  intros n. intros m. left.
  destruct H. firstorder.
```

The state at the end of this block of code is:

```
2 subgoals
n, m, x : nat
H : n + m = 2 * x + 1
______________________________________(1/2)
odd n
______________________________________(2/2)
even m
```

To my understanding, it is telling me that I need to prove to it that I have an odd number n and an even number m through the hypothesis? Even though I have already stated than n is odd and m is even? How do I proceed from here?

UPDATE:

After a bit of fidgeting around (in light of the comments), I guess I would have to do something like this?

```
Lemma even_or_odd: forall (n: nat), even n \/ odd n.
Proof.
  induction n as [|n IHn].
  (* Base Case *)
  left. unfold even. exists 0. firstorder.
  (* step case *)
  destruct IHn as [IHeven | IHodd].
  right. unfold even in IHeven. destruct IHeven as [k Heq].
  unfold odd. exists k. firstorder.
  left. unfold odd in IHodd. destruct IHodd as [k Heq].
  unfold even. exists (k + 1). firstorder.
Qed.
```

Which means that now:

```
Lemma sum_odd : forall n m, odd (n + m) -> odd n /\ even m \/ even n /\ odd m.
Proof.
  intros n. intros m. left. destruct H. firstorder.
  pose proof (even_or_odd n). pose proof (even_or_odd m).
```

Result:

```
    2 subgoals
n, m, x : nat
H : n + m = 2 * x + 1
H0 : even n \/ odd n
H1 : even m \/ odd m
______________________________________(1/2)
odd n
______________________________________(2/2)
even m
```

Intuitively, all that I have done is saying that every number is either even or odd. Now I have to tell coq that my odd and even numbers are indeed odd and even (I guess?).

UPDATE 2:

As an aside, the problem is solvable with just firstorder:

```
Lemma sum_odd : forall n m, odd (n + m) -> odd n /\ even m \/ even n /\ odd m.
Proof.
  intros n. intros m. firstorder.
  pose proof (even_or_odd n). pose proof (even_or_odd m).
  destruct H0 as [Even_n | Odd_n]. destruct H1 as [Even_m | Odd_m].
  exfalso. firstorder.
  right. auto.
  destruct H1. left. auto.
  exfalso. firstorder.
Qed.
```

Comment: Where do you think you stated that n is odd and m is even? You used `left` to indicate that you wanted to prove those two things (instead of `even n /\ odd m`), but before you do that you need to do some induction/case analysis.

Comment: You're saying that you need to prove this by induction? Why? The classical way of proving this is simply by stating: `n = 2a + 1`, `m = 2b` therefore `n + m = 2a + 1 + 2b` => `n + m = 2(a + b) + 1`. I cannot find an apparent way of doing this proof by definition/substitution in coq. I suppose I just (erroneously) assumed that coq would assume n is odd and m is even, since to prove `odd (n + m) -> odd n /\ even m` requires the assumption that n is odd and m is even.

Comment: The argument "`n = 2a + 1`, `m = 2b` therefore `n + m = 2a + 1 + 2b`" proves `odd n /\ even m -> odd (n + m)`, not the inverse that you are trying to prove.

Comment: Update, thank you for the input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of `left` is still incorrect and keeps you from completing the proof. You apply it to the following goal:

```
odd (n + m) -> odd n /\ even m \/ even n /\ odd m
```

and it gives:

```
H : odd (n + m)
______________________________________(1/1)
odd n /\ even m
```

*You are committing to proving that if `n + m` is odd, then `n` is odd and `m` is even.* But this is not true: `n` might be odd and `m` might be even. Only apply `left` or `right` once you have enough information in the context to be sure which one you want to prove.

So let's restart without `left`:

```
Lemma sum_odd : forall n m, odd (n + m) -> odd n /\ even m \/ even n /\ odd m.
Proof.
  intros n. intros m. firstorder.
  pose proof (even_or_odd n). pose proof (even_or_odd m).
```

At this point we are at:

```
H : n + m = 2 * x + 1
H0 : even n \/ odd n
H1 : even m \/ odd m
______________________________________(1/1)
odd n /\ even m \/ even n /\ odd m
```

Now you want to prove something from disjunctions. In order to prove something of the form `A \/ B -> C` in Coq's constructive logic, you must prove *both* `A -> C` and `B -> C`. You do this by case analysis on the `A \/ B` (using `destruct` or other tactics). In this case we have two disjunctions to decompose:

```
  destruct H0 as [Even_n | Odd_n], H1 as [Even_m | Odd_m].
```

This gives four cases. I'll show you the first two, the last two are symmetric.

Fist case:

```
H : n + m = 2 * x + 1
Even_n : even n
Even_m : even m
______________________________________(1/1)
odd n /\ even m \/ even n /\ odd m
```

The assumptions are contradictory: If both `n` and `m` are even, then `H` cannot hold. We can prove this as follows:

```
  - exfalso. destruct Even_n, Even_m. omega.
```

(Step through this to understand what happens!) The `exfalso` is not really necessary, but it's good documentation that we are doing a proof by showing that the assumptions contradict.

Second case:

```
H : n + m = 2 * x + 1
Even_n : even n
Odd_m : odd m
______________________________________(1/1)
odd n /\ even m \/ even n /\ odd m
```

*Now*, knowing assumptions that apply in *this case*, we can commit to the *right* disjunct. This is why your `left` kept you from making progress!

```
  - right.
```

All that remains to be proved is:

```
Even_n : even n
Odd_m : odd m
______________________________________(1/1)
even n /\ odd m
```

And `auto` can handle this.